# Recommendations on deploying create-react-app with node backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, nginx

I am trying to deploy my React app that uses a node.js express backend (running on a AWS EC2 instance). I am having trouble deciding how to deploy my React App to make sure it can fetch from the backend.

1. I can set my website example.com to direct to a AWS S3 static hosting that has my React app. In this case, I would have to have to hard code my ec2 public ip e.g. fetch("http://12.35.143.34/api/users/1") in the React code.
2. I can set my website example.com to direct to an ec2 instance with Nginx that will direct /api calls to the server and any other type of calls to the S3 bucket.

I read different posts about both ways so I am confused on which way is right.

Edit: Or is there a third option such as an api subdomain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to run a NodeJS based application on AWS. The best one for you depends on your case, and how your app is developed.

1. Use [AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/?nc1=h_ls)

- It is a PaaS service that lets you run your application on top of AWS infrastructure, without you having to configure these services individually.
- [Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs.html)

2. Use [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/#) + [AWS API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/?nc1=h_ls)

- If your codebase supports it, this is a very scalable, cheap, and performant way to run your app.
- You might have to rewrite part of your code. It depends on how your backend is written. If you are using `express`, it is simple to migrate it to AWS Lambda.
- [Migrating an Express Application to Amazon API Gateway and AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/going-serverless-migrating-an-express-application-to-amazon-api-gateway-and-aws-lambda/)

3. EC2 using [ELB](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/) and [Auto Scaling Groups](https://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/).

- Regardless of the size of your application, you should run it with some level of high availability and load balancing.
- You shouldn't run your application on just one node; you should use an Auto Scaling Group.
- You shouldn't publish your EC2 instances directly on the Internet; you should use an Application Load Balancer.
- If your application uses a database, you should try to move it to RDS, and not run it by yourself.

And finally, to answer your question, I would recommend 3: you should use multiple CloudFront origins. Us an S3 bucket origin to hold the static data, and an ELB origin for the dynamic, non-cacheable content. [Check this post for more information on how to do it](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/dynamic-whole-site-delivery-with-amazon-cloudfront/).

If you own a domain, you can also create a certificate and serve your content through HTTPS, handled by CloudFront.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for this informative comment (I am using 3.) However my current concern is more about should I use 1. or 2. (my post)

Comment: You were right; I hadn't answered your question. I have edited my answer to fix this. Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 1):

My way :

1.deploy your node app to EC2 try to attach a DNS or just use the given one by aws - [here](https://hackernoon.com/deploying-a-node-app-on-amazon-ec2-d2fb9a6757eb)

2.test your api using postman.

3.change the api url endpoint value to the api DNS

4.deploy (upload) your dist/ (build directory) - [here](https://medium.com/@wolovim/deploying-create-react-app-to-s3-or-cloudfront-48dae4ce0af)

5.config the bucket to act as a static website host - [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html)

6.(optional) try to configure the CloudFront to your bucket and get app dns - [here](https://johnlouros.com/blog/using-CloudFront-to-serve-an-SPA-from-S3)

Comment: For 3. and 6. which DNS are you referring to? How can I have two endpoints for the same DNS? Do you mean to use api.example.com and example.com?

Comment: 3 API DNS (DNS related to EC2 instance). 6 DNS to configure if you want access to react app (it's optional )